# Is this officially the proper way of using get and set in Swift?

Tags: swift, standards

Let's say for example I want to make some kind of a radio button which keeps track of its active state and changes color when its state is changed. I want it to change color as I set the value. This is how I would implement it:

```
class TagButton: UIButton {

    var _active: Bool = false

    var active: Bool {
        set(newVal){
            _active = newVal
            if(!newVal){
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white //inactive
            }
            else {
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red //active
            }
        }
        get {
            return _active
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I have seen some questions suggest a similar approach, but what bothers me, is whether or not this is actually intended use of Swift. I have a feeling I am inventing a bicycle here. And I could not find anything about this in official Swift documentation. Was anyone able to confirm this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks like Objective-C.  In Swift, there is no need to create the backing storage and you can use the property observer `didSet` to change the background color:

```
class TagButton: UIButton {
    var active = false {
        didSet {
            backgroundColor = active ? .red : .white
        }
    }
}
```

---

Or you could use a Computed Property and not have storage for `active` at all:

```
class TagButton: UIButton {
    var active: Bool {
        set {
            backgroundColor = newValue ? .red : .white
        }
        get {
            return backgroundColor == .red
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more about *Property Observers* and *Computed Properties* [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)

Comment: What if I want a custom set method?

Comment: @IlyaLapan: A custom method for doing what?

Comment: @appzYourLife Not in this particular case, but in general, what if I not only needed a custom getter but a custom setter too?

Comment: @IlyaLapan: In that case yes, you should probably use a private storage value and define a computed property with `get` and `set`.

Comment: @appzYourLife Have you seen any examples in Swift documentation or anything official from Apple on the topic?

Comment: @IlyaLapan: Look at the _Computed Properties_ paragraph [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html).